# MSSQL-Server/ruby-gem sequel: How to read UTF-8 values?

Tags: ruby, sql-server, sql-server-2005, encoding, sequel

I use the [ruby-gem sequel](http://rubygems.org/gems/sequel) to read utf-8-encoded data from a MSSQL-Server table.
The fields of the table are defined as `nvarchar`, they look correct in the Microsoft Server Management Studio (Cyrillic is Cyrillic, Chinese looks chinese).

I connect my database with

```
  db = Sequel.connect(
    :adapter=>'ado', 
    :host     =>connectiondata[:server], 
    :database=>connectiondata[:dsn], 
    #Login via SSO
  )

  sel = db[:TEXTE].filter(:language=> 'EN') 
  sel.each{|data| 
    data.each{|key, val|
      puts "#{val.encoding}: #{val.inspect}"  #-> CP850: ....
      puts val.encode('utf-8')
    }
  }
```

This works fine for English, German returns also a useable result:

```
CP850: "(2 St\x81ck) f\x81r
(2 Stück) für ...
```

But the result is converted to `CP850`, it is not the original `UTF-8`.

Cyrillic languages (I tested with Bulgarian) and Chinese produce only '?'
(reasonable, because `CP850` doesn't include Chinese and Bulgarian characters).

I also connected via a odbc-connection:

```
    db = Sequel.odbc(odbckey,
      :db_type => 'mssql',  #necessary
      #:encoding => 'utf-8',  #Only MySQL-Adapter
    )
```

The result is `ASCII-8BIT`, I have to convert the data with `force_encoding` to CP1252 (not CP850!).
But Cyrillic and Chinese is still not possible.

What I tried already:

- The MySQL-adapter seems to have an encoding option, with MSSQL I detected no effect.
- I did similar tests with sqlite and sequel and I had no problem with unicode.
- I installed `SQLNCLI10.dll` and used it as provider. But I get a *Invalid connection string attribute*-error (same with `sqlncli`).

So my closing question: How can I read UTF-8 data in MS-SQL via ruby and sequel?

My environment:

Client:

- Windows 7
- Ruby 1.9.2
- sequel-3.33.0

Database:

- SQL Server 2005
- Database has collation Latin1_General_CI_AS

After preparing my question I found a solution. I will post it as an answer.
But I still hope, there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can avoid it, you really don't want to use the ado adapter (it's OK for read-only workloads, but I wouldn't recommend it for other workloads).  I would try the tinytds adapter, as I believe that will handle encodings properly, and it defaults to UTF-8.

Sequel itself does not do any transcoding, it leaves the handling of encodings to the lower level driver.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I saw tinytds in advance, but I wanted to avoid it (I don't want to install another programm). I looked again to the gem. It seems, there is also [win32-version](http://rubygems.org/gems/tiny_tds/versions/0.5.1-x86-mingw32) of the gem including tinytds. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: I just tested with the win32-gem and it works, there was no need of an additional installation. There is one drop of bitterness: No SSO, I need user and password. I will research for this, but this question has now two working solutionsThanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After preparing my question I found a solution on my own.

When I add a

```
Encoding.default_external='utf-8'
```

to my code, I get the correct results.

As a side effect each `File.open` expects now also UTF-8-encoded files (This can be overwritten by additional parameters in `File.open`).

As an alternative, this works also:

```
Encoding.default_internal='utf-8'
```

As I mentioned in my question, I don't like to change global settings, only to change the behaviour of one interface.

So I still hope on a better solution.